# Can't see how RXJS determines which part of shared operation to repeat on multiple subscriptions

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The operator *share()* discussed [here in the learning docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share), shows two examples of how the result will be with it and without it. I understand why the *side effect* only shows once - it's because we **share** the source. I also tried checking [the official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) but it gave me little wisdom.

I don't understand why we get to see the main result for each subscription. I get that it's the intended result but I can't see how the computer knows what's side-effect and what's main-effect.

```
const source = timer(1000);
const example = source.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("side-effect)),
  mapTo("main-effect")
);

const shared = example.pipe(share());
const go1 = shared.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
const go2 = shared.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, the answer is quite straight forward: Everything before the share() operator will execute only once. Everything after the share() operator will execute as many times as there are subscriptions.

In your example above, first there will be only one stream that in initialized from the timer. Every second you will have one event that first goes to the tap, then to the mapTo, then to the share. After the share the stream breaks up into two different streams, one for each subscribe.

timer -> tap -> mapTo -> share -> splits up into two different streams

The mapTo operator creates the string "main-effect" once, and then sends it down the pipe. When the stream is split into two, the string "main-effect" is copied and sent down to both of the subscribers, so that is why they both receive the string.

Comment: Where are you located at the moment?

Comment: I am in Oslo, what about you?

Comment: Stockholm. So it's not called *Snorre* in Norwegian? Good to know.   :)

Comment: No it is not :) or if it is, then nobody has told me yet